# Possible to transfer BTC via QR code?

Tags: qrcode

Is it possible to embed an amount of BTC in a QR code to transfer to whoever scans it?

E.g. I create a QR code for .5 BTC from my wallet, send the QR code to someone (without knowing their BTC wallet address), they scan it using their wallet app and receive it?

Answer (score 1):

Just add amount parameter to QR data:

```
bitcoin:1ArmoryXcfq7TnCSuZa9fQjRYwJ4bkRKfv?amount=0.005
```

use google chart to generate QR

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=bitcoin:1ArmoryXcfq7TnCSuZa9fQjRYwJ4bkRKfv?&amount=0.005

---

> if you are asking about auto sending bitcoin through QR so it's not possible.

Comment: That is to request an amount, not send an amount

Answer (score 0):

Answer I received on Reddit:

Yes. Create a paper wallet at bitaddress.org; send any amount of bitcoins to the qr code on the left that has the word "SHARE" next to it. Then, you can send the qr code on the right, the one that says "Secret," to the person who you want to receive the bitcoins. If they scan that qr code, the one that says "secret," they can receive the bitcoins you sent to the "Share" qr code into their bitcoin wallet.

Comment: This answer isn't for this question. Giving anyone your private key of this address giving them the access to bitcoins in this address.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want. You create a new wallet, transfer the BTC to it, embed private keys, then anyone can take that BTC.